# How do I see Node.js errors?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I'm new to Node.js.  I know there are more involved debuggers available (like node_debug and ndb), but is there a simple way to see runtime errors thrown in Node.js?

With a simple example file like this:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var foo = [1, 2, 3];
    foo.append(4);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('Ok', 'utf-8');
    res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

the `foo.append(4);` line fails, but that error doesn't ever seem to get propagated to the console, and I don't see it in Console.app or STD_ERR either.

Is there a way to view that error?

Answer (score 1):

Updating my copy of Node.js (from v0.1.95 to v0.1.99) seems to have fixed it.